# Genotype data - How to import using R

Tags: r, file, import

I am a new member of stackoverflow, and I am starting to work in R, so I need some help!

I have a file with 740 rows and 500 000 columns, separated by tab, and format .txt . The size of the file is about 1.2GB. This file contains information about cattle's genotype. I need to read this file into an R program to perform association studies analysis with the phenotype data. I can not import this big file in R. Someone know a command to do this? Just a command for import this file and read it in R?

My system: i5 and 6Gb of RAM memory.

Comment: This is a very basic function in R. If your problem is one that you think others have had before, you should check R manuals/documentation and a basic google search first. Read chapter seven of http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf , the basic R manual, to learn about importing data. If you still have issues after an hour or so of work, then let us know the problem.

Answer (score 3):

read.table() is what you need. Does your file have headers?

On Linux (no headers in file):
`mydata = read.table("/home/username/genotype.txt", header=FALSE)`

On Linux (with headers in file):
`mydata = read.table("/home/username/genotype.txt", header=TRUE)`

On Windows (no headers in file):
`mydata = read.table("c:\\mydata\\genotype.txt", header=FALSE)`

On Windows (with headers in file): 
`mydata = read.table("c:\\mydata\\genotype.txt", header=TRUE)`

`read.table()` uses tab as the separator by default but you can specify the argument sep="," (or sep="|" etc) to specify a different separator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the read.table command can import large files??

Comment: depends on what you mean by "large". I have used it to read in files with 500,000 - 800,000 rows and 100+ columns, with a mix of numerical and text data. Depends on your hardware and OS too.

Answer (score 1):

in R, you can type `?read.csv` and `?read.table` which will give you the help files for those functions.

You can then assign the output of this function to a variable, which will be your data frame.

For example:

```
  myDataFrame <- read.csv("path/to/file.txt", sep="\t")
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers address the general problem of reading data in to R, but your data is of a particular type; there are some excellent 'domain-specific' packages available on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org) and [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) as well as [in the wild](http://www.bios.unc.edu/research/genomic_software/Matrix_eQTL/). These packages will have their own ways of inputting this data, perhaps transformed from your current representation, but likely will have significant benefits in efficient handling and performance of common operations. Better to pursue these, while at the same time learning how to use general features of R.